# Loading GLSL shader without using any Apple APIs

Tags: ios, input, io, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

What is a good way to load a GLSL shader using C/C++ without using Objective-C or any Apple APIs?

I am currently using the following method, which is from the *iPhone 3D Programming* book, but it says that it is not recommended for production code:

Simple.vsh

```
const char* SimpleVertexShader = STRINGIFY
(

// Shader code...

);
```

RenderingEngine.cpp

```
#define STRINGIFY(A) #A
#include "Simple.vsh"

// ...

glShaderSource( shaderHandle, 1, &SimpleVertexShader, 0 );
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use Objective-C?

Comment: I want to keep my RenderingEngine class pure C++...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load your shaders from files in your app bundle, you can get the file paths using the `NSBundle` object (in Objective-C), or using the CoreFoundation `CFBundle` object (in pure C).

Either way, you are using Apple-specific APIs.  The only thing you're getting by using `CFBundle` instead of `NSBundle` is more boilerplate code.

If you don't want to use any Apple APIs, then your options are to embed your shaders as literal strings, or connect to a server on the Internet and download them (using the Unix socket API).

What you *really* need to do is define an interface by which your RenderingEngine gets the source code for its shaders, and implement that interface using the appropriate platform-specific API on each platform to which your port the RenderingEngine.  The interface can be something super simple like this:

#### RenderingEngineShaderSourceInterface.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// You are responsible for freeing the C string that this function returns.
extern char const *RenderingEngine_shaderSourceForName(char const *name);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then you create `RenderingEngineShaderSource_Windows.cpp`, `RenderingEngineShaderSource_iOS.m`, `RenderingEngineShaderSource_Linux.cpp`, etc.  Each one implements `RenderingEngine_shaderSourceForName` using the appropriate API for that platform.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified in the OP that I don't want to use any Apple APIs. I'll edit the title...

Answer (score 0):

I use one of two methods. If it's a short shader, I may just put it code:

```
const char   shader[] = 
"uniform vec4 blah;\n" // Note, no semicolon here - it does the right thing
"main ()\n"
"{\n"
...rest of code
"}\n";
```

Or, if it's longer or going to be re-used in other places, I'll put it into a text file in the resources and read the text file at run time. You can get to it via [NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:].

Comment: I would like to use something like the second method, but I do not want to use any Objective-C.

Comment: You can read the file other ways, such as using an ifstream or FILE operations (fopen(), fread(), fclose(), etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Consider a C++ raw string literal; no `STRINGIFY` is needed since the newer features of C++ allow you to do similar things without macro.

I'd retype a good example but [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13872584/768472).