# GCC, stringification, and inline GLSL?

Tags: c++, opengl, gcc, glsl, c-preprocessor

I'd like to declare GLSL shader strings inline using macro stringification:

```
#define STRINGIFY(A)  #A
const GLchar* vert = STRINGIFY(
#version 120\n
attribute vec2 position;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4( position, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
);
```

This builds and runs fine using VS2010 but fails to compile on `gcc` with:

```
error: invalid preprocessing directive #version
```

Is there a way to use stringification like this in a portable manner?

I'm trying to avoid per-line quotes:

```
const GLchar* vert = 
"#version 120\n"
"attribute vec2 position;"
"void main()"
"{"
"    gl_Position = vec4( position, 0.0, 1.0 );"
"}"
;
```

...and/or line continuation:

```
const GLchar* vert = "\
#version 120\n                                 \
attribute vec2 position;                       \
void main()                                    \
{                                              \
    gl_Position = vec4( position, 0.0, 1.0 );  \
}                                              \
";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stringification - how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989730/stringification-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Can you use C++11?  If so you could use [raw string literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#New_string_literals):

```
const GLchar* vert = R"END(
#version 120
attribute vec2 position;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4( position, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
)END";
```

No need for escapes or explicit newlines.  These strings start with an R (or r).  You need a delimiter (I chose END) between the quote and the first parenthesis to escape parenthesis which you have in the code snippet.

Comment: This is mostly for streamlining [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) programs/examples here on SO so in the interests of portability I'd like to avoid C++11.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. GLSL shaders and OpenCL kernels are one of the best use-cases for raw string literals. But note, that the delimiter is not strictly neccessary, it can just be empty, only the `R"()"` is mandatory.

Comment: @ChristianRau You're right.  I only need the END to escape a literal )" not just ).

Comment: Note, some GLSL compilers hew *very* closely to the spec ([ANGLE](https://github.com/google/angle)'s, for instance) & may reject shaders with an initial newline before the `#version` directive. A quick solution is to add one to the pointer to skip over it: `const char* vert = 1 + R"END(`...

Comment: @genpfault Or just start out with `const GLchar* vert = R"END(#version 120` without the newline. I just wrote my answer that way to make it look nicer. (To me).

Comment: @genpfault: Sounds like they're not following the spec closely, as it says: "The #version directive must occur in a shader before anything else, except for comments and white space.",  and newlines are whitespace.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Hrm, good point, thanks!  I might have to check ANGLE's compilation pipeline & file a bug.

Answer (score 20):

Unfortunately, having preprocessor directives in the argument of a macro is undefined, so you can't do this directly.  But as long as none of your shaders need preprocessor directives other than `#version`, you could do something like:

```
#define GLSL(version, shader)  "#version " #version "\n" #shader

const GLchar* vert = GLSL(120,
    attribute vec2 position;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = vec4( position, 0.0, 1.0 );
    }
);
```

Comment: I like to target un-extended GLSL so this works great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To achieve this purpose I used sed. I have seperate files with GLSL which I edit (with proper syntax highlighting), and in the same time GLSL in inlined in C++. Not very cross platform, but with msys it works under windows.

In C++ code:

```
const GLchar* vert = 
#include "shader_processed.vert"
;
```

In Makefile:

```
shader_processed.vert: shader.vert
    sed -f shader.sed shader.vert > shader_processed.vert

programm: shader_processed.vert main.cpp
    g++ ...
```

shader.sed

```
s|\\|\\\\|g
s|"|\\"|g
s|$|\\n"|g
s|^|"|g
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is due to gcc preprocessing macros meant for GLSL. Using standard stringify and escaping preprocessor directives with new lines in GLSL code worked for me.

```
#define STRINGIFY(A)  #A

const GLchar* vert = STRINGIFY(

\n#version 120\n
\n#define MY_MACRO 999\n

attribute vec2 position;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4( position, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach: include a header file, but with a `.glsl` extension.

For example, I have a file called `bar.h.glsl`. It exposes my vertex and fragment shader code as raw literals:

```c
#pragma once

namespace bar {

static const char vertex[] = R"(#version 410 core


// ----- vertex shader start -----
layout( location = 0 ) in vec4 vPosition;

uniform float Time;
uniform float Width;

void main()
{
    float x = vPosition.x;
    float y = vPosition.y * Width;
    float yOffset = mix(sin(Time), sin(Time * 0.75), x * 0.5 + 0.5);
    gl_Position = vec4(x, y + yOffset, vPosition.z, vPosition.w);
}
// ------ vertex shader end ------


)";
static const char fragment[] = R"(#version 410 core


// ----- fragment shader start ----
out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
// ------ fragment shader end -----


)";

}
```

Then in my source, I simply include the file:

```
#include "bar.h.glsl"
```

and access the glsl strings like so:

```
bool success = barShader.Compile( bar::vertex, bar::fragment );
```

This way, although I need to overlook a bit of C code in my glsl files, I get the best of glsl syntax highlighting without having to dynamically load the file.