# Stringification - how does it work?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, stringification

I know that:

```
#define foo 4  
#define str(s) #s
```

with `str(foo)` writes out: `"foo"`, because stringify is executed first of text expansion, but this:

```
 #define xstr(s) str(s)
 #define str(s) #s
 #define foo 4
```

with `xstr(foo)` writes out: `"4"`.

Why? What are the steps involved in the process?

Comment: @alk the link has changed. Correct link is: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The relevant steps of macro expansion are (per C 2011 [n1570] 6.10.3.1 and C++ 1998 16.3.1):

1. Process tokens that are preceded by `#` or `##`.
2. Apply macro replacement to each argument.
3. Replace each parameter with the corresponding result of the above macro replacement.
4. Rescan for more macros.

Thus, with `xstr(foo)`, we have:

1. The replacement text, `str(s)`, contains no `#` or `##`, so nothing happens.
2. The argument `foo` is replaced with `4`, so it is as if `xstr(4)` had been used.
3. In the replacement text `str(s)`, the parameter `s` is replaced with `4`, producing `str(4)`.
4. `str(4)` is rescanned. (The resulting steps produce `”4”`.)

Note that the problem with `str(foo)` is that step 2, which would replace `foo` with `4`, comes after step 1, which changes the argument to a string. In step 1, `foo` is still `foo`; it has not been replaced with `4`, so the result is `”foo”`.

This is why a helper macro is used. It allows us to get a step 2 performed, then use another macro to perform step 1.

Comment: At last! I finally understood why this works like this, after reading this answer. I even was using it correctly by intuition, but couldn't come to the rule. The `stringify` macro comes up in many places (e.g. appending `__LINE__` to identifier - to force it to be expanded and not left as `__LINE__`, in that case you'll use `##` instead of `#`), or - more recently needed to pass arguments to GCC's `_Pragma()` macro (intrinsic?), which accepts a quoted string, so you may need: `#define my_pragma(arg) _Pragma(stringify("blah " #arg " blah2"))`.

Comment: #define PE(BZL,YY) printf("ERROR - " #BZL ": result: 0x%08x!", YY); Doing:int variable1=1; PE(Test1,variable1); --> Results printing: ERROR - Test1: result: 0x1!

Answer (score 16):

### First case

1. Evaluate `str(foo)`: Substitute `str(foo)` with `#foo`, ie `"foo"`

### Second case

1. Evaluate `xstr(foo)`: Substitute `xstr(foo)` with `str(<foo-value>)`, ie `str(4)`
2. Evaluate `str(4)`: Substitute `str(4)` with `#4`, ie `"4"`

### Generally,

preprocessor evaluates macro-functions expanding macro-variables, *until it is nothing to evaluate*:

If you define

```
#define xstr(s) str(s) + 1
#define str(s) s + 1
```

in the following code

```
#define foo 4

int main()
{
    std::cout << str(foo) << '\n' 
              << xstr(foo) << '\n' ;

}
```

it would evaluate like

#### First string

1. Substitute `str(foo)` with `<foo-value> + 1`, ie `4 + 1`
2. Nothing more to substitute. Finishing.

And result is 4 + 1

#### Second string

1. Substitute `xstr(foo)` with `str(<foo-value>) + 1`, ie `str(4) + 1`
2. Substitute `str(4)` with `<4-value> + 1`, ie `4 + 1`
3. Nothing more to substitute.

And result is 4 + 1 + 1

Comment: I still don't understand.. First case: 1) Stringify foo 2) Expand, I now have foo. Second case: 1) Stringify, there's nothing to stringify.. 2) expand, I now have str(s) 3) stringify, now I have str(s) foo 4) Expand, now I have foo. Why is it different??

Comment: @DavidKernin, Well, _do_ you understand, that 'stringify' operation is `#`? It is only one step.

Comment: @DavidKernin, this just not so smart, as you believe. It is pretty dumb. It just expands everything.

Comment: I got it, it's like a stack of functions.. it just keeps substituting until it encounters a # then stops the substitution. Returning from these "functions" substitutions continue if there is no other #.