# What does '#' exactly do in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define f(a,b) a##b
#define g(a)   #a
#define h(a) g(a)

int main()
{
      printf("%s\n",h(f(1,2)));
      printf("%s\n",g(f(1,2)));
      return 0;
}
```

This program working properly and giving output as:

```
12
f(1, 2)
```

I don't understand how compiler giving this output.

What is the function of # in `a##b` and `#a`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989730/c-stringify-how-does-it-work

Comment: @YuHao , I'm really sorry. I searched for this question. I didn't get any related. because i don't know # is called stringify.

Comment: @SGG Hey, that's all right because it's hard to search for this question as there's no particular keyword. I remember seeing this program before and still spent several minutes to find the duplicate:) Even knowing the basic usage of `#` and `##`, this question is still hard to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let me break it down for you :

```
#define f(a,b) a##b //2 this macro is evaluated first with a = 1 and b = 2 it concatenates them and returns 12
#define g(a)   #a //4 g turns 12 into "12" (string)
#define h(a) g(a) //3 back to h which now has a = 12 and call g()

int main()
{
      printf("%s\n",h(f(1,2)));//1 printf calls the macro h() and gives it the macro f() as an argument 
      printf("%s\n",g(f(1,2)));// g here turns f(1,2) into "f(1,2)" (string)
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Generally right, but after (1) comes first the `h()` definition as (2), which in turn "activates" `f()`, which would be (3) and then `g()` (4).

Answer (score 12):

The `##` concatenates two tokens together.

The important thing is it can only be used in the preprocessor.

The `#` operator is used to  stringify tokens.

**For example:-**

`#(a ## b)` which becomes `#ab` which becomes `"ab"`

So h(f(1,2)) becomes "f(1,2)"

Also note that `#` and `##` are two different operators.

> The preprocessor operator **##** provides a way to concatenate actual
>   arguments during macro expansion. If a parameter in the replacement
>   text is adjacent to a ##, the parameter is replaced by the actual
>   argument, the ## and surrounding white space are removed, and the
>   result is re-scanned.

Also check this **[Concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198442/what-does-exactly-do-in-c/19198458?noredirect=1#comment28407949_19198458)** for more details.

From [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/cpp_3.html):-

> **Stringification**
>
> Sometimes you may want to convert a macro argument into a string
>   constant. Parameters are not replaced inside string constants, but you
>   can use the **'#' preprocessing operator instead**. When a macro parameter
>   is used with a leading `#', the preprocessor replaces it with the
>   literal text of the actual argument, converted to a string constant.
>   Unlike normal parameter replacement, the argument is not
>   macro-expanded first. This is called stringification.
>
> There is no way to combine an argument with surrounding text and
>   stringify it all together. Instead, you can write a series of adjacent
>   string constants and stringified arguments. The preprocessor will
>   replace the stringified arguments with string constants. The C
>   compiler will then combine all the adjacent string constants into one
>   long string.

Comment: +1 You may want to mention that `#` and `##` are two different operators.

Comment: Why the difference in results if we have almost identical calls?

Comment: @self. How they are "almost identical"? 2*12 and 2+12 are as well "almost identical" and produce completely different results.

Comment: @glglgl You explanation is useless.

Comment: @self. No. It shows that a seemingly minor difference can make a significant difference. Concerning the question, `f(1,2)` produces `12`. But `g()` just takes its argument and makes it a string, producing `"f(1, 2)"` (the space probably comes from the lexer or the parser). But if you feed `h()` with the `f()` call, you have one level of indirection more: `h()` references to `g()`, during which process the `f(1,2)` is expanded to `12`, which is what `g()` now stringizes, leading to the equivalent of `"12"`.

Answer (score 4):

`##` is called "token-pasting" operator, or "merging" operator which can be used to combine two tokens to form an actual argument.

`#` is called Stringizing Operator which "converts macro parameters to string literals without expanding the parameter definition".

These are generally called Preprocessor Operators. There exists a few more preprocessor operators like these. Check out Preprocessor Operators in C (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wy090hkc.aspx) for more explanation.

---

Also checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sxhs2ty.aspx and the "see also" section of that page for more information on C Preprocessor.