# Macro that expands its only argument into its component characters

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to write a macro in C/C++ pre-processer that expands its single argument to the component characters it is composed of

For example

```
EXPAND( abcd )
```

would expand to

```
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
```

Other examples are

```
EXPAND( 1 )
'1'
EXPAND( 12 )
'1', '2'
EXPAND( func_name )
'f', 'u', 'n', 'c', '_', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e'
```

**EDIT:**

The purpose would be to pass a character sequence as a parameter to a template like the one below

```
template<char...  args>
struct  Struct {
    ... 
};
```

Instead of having to code the tedious

```
Struct<'a', 'b', 'c'>
```

one would simply do

```
Struct<EXPAND( abc )>
```

Ideally it would be best if one could code

```
Struct<"abc">
```

but string literals are not converted into char... sequences automatically.

Comment: No. IMHO macros are best to avoid

Comment: What purpose would such a macro serve? It would just make the code even harder to understand.

Comment: I added an explanation of the purpose as an edit.

Comment: You might want to share more of the idea of this template. Maybe the idea is fundamentally broken and another approach can eliminate the requirement you are asking for.

Comment: Have a look at this:  http://abel.web.elte.hu/mpllibs/metaparse/string.html  I think it does exactly what you are asking for.  Here is an overview: http://2012.cppnow.org/session/metaparse-complie-time-parsing-with-template-metaprogramming/ and http://web.archive.org/web/20140217173026/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2012/10/using-strings-in-c-template-metaprograms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This functionality is not provided by the C preprocessor.

Depending on your use case, a string might be equivalent (except for the null byte), so [stringifying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989730/stringification-how-does-it-work) might work as well.

You might have a look at [m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html), a more advanced preprocessor by K&R. Maybe it provides the functionality you need.