# C++ Macro to create a string array

Tags: c++, preprocessor

Is there a way to create a `std::string` (or `char*`) array with a pre-processor macro?

Something like this:

```
std::string myStrings[] = {MAGIC_MACRO(a, b, c)};
```

Result:

```
std::string myStrings[] = {"a", "b", "c"}
```

I know it looks pointless but I need it in a more complicated macro that has a variable number of arguments

Comment: No, you can't do it. Specially not the way to replace `{}` by `[]`.

Comment: The result part was not clear sorry, see my edit

Comment: Is there a limit to the amount of arguments, or should it support an arbitrary amount?

Comment: No limits. Something like `MAGIC_MACRO(...)`

Comment: This is probably going to depend on what the "more complicated macro" currently looks like.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I don't think so, it is unrelated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below is working for what you've asked for with up to 1024 arguments and **without** using additional stuff like boost. It defines an `EVAL(...)` and also a `MAP(m, first, ...)` macro to do recursion and to use for each iteration the macro `m` with the next parameter `first`.

With the use of that, your `MAGIC_MACRO(...)` looks like: `#define MAGIC_MACRO(...) EVAL(MAP(STRINGIZE, __VA_ARGS__))`.

It is mostly copied from [C Pre-Processor Magic](http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic). It is also great explained there. You can also download these helper macros like `EVAL(...)` at this [git repository](https://github.com/18sg/uSHET/blob/master/lib/cpp_magic.h), there are also a lot of explanation in the actual code. It is variadic so it takes the number of arguments you want.

But I changed the `FIRST` and the `SECOND` macro as it uses a Gnu extension like it is in the source I've copied it from.

**Main function part:**

```
int main()
{
   std::string myStrings[] = { MAGIC_MACRO(a, b, c) }; // Expands to: std::string myStrings[] = { "a" , "b" , "c" };
   std::string myStrings[] = { MAGIC_MACRO(a, b, c, x, y, z) }; // Expands to: std::string myStrings[] = { "a" , "b" , "c", "x" , "y" , "z" };
}
```

**Macro definitions:**

```
#define FIRST_(a, ...) a
#define SECOND_(a, b, ...) b

#define FIRST(...) FIRST_(__VA_ARGS__,)
#define SECOND(...) SECOND_(__VA_ARGS__,)

#define EMPTY()

#define EVAL(...) EVAL1024(__VA_ARGS__)
#define EVAL1024(...) EVAL512(EVAL512(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL512(...) EVAL256(EVAL256(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL256(...) EVAL128(EVAL128(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL128(...) EVAL64(EVAL64(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL64(...) EVAL32(EVAL32(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL32(...) EVAL16(EVAL16(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL16(...) EVAL8(EVAL8(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL8(...) EVAL4(EVAL4(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL4(...) EVAL2(EVAL2(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL2(...) EVAL1(EVAL1(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL1(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define DEFER1(m) m EMPTY()
#define DEFER2(m) m EMPTY EMPTY()()

#define IS_PROBE(...) SECOND(__VA_ARGS__, 0)
#define PROBE() ~, 1

#define CAT(a,b) a ## b

#define NOT(x) IS_PROBE(CAT(_NOT_, x))
#define _NOT_0 PROBE()

#define BOOL(x) NOT(NOT(x))

#define IF_ELSE(condition) _IF_ELSE(BOOL(condition))
#define _IF_ELSE(condition) CAT(_IF_, condition)

#define _IF_1(...) __VA_ARGS__ _IF_1_ELSE
#define _IF_0(...)             _IF_0_ELSE

#define _IF_1_ELSE(...)
#define _IF_0_ELSE(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define COMMA ,

#define HAS_ARGS(...) BOOL(FIRST(_END_OF_ARGUMENTS_ __VA_ARGS__)())
#define _END_OF_ARGUMENTS_() 0

#define MAP(m, first, ...)           \
  m(first)                           \
  IF_ELSE(HAS_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))(    \
    COMMA DEFER2(_MAP)()(m, __VA_ARGS__)   \
  )(                                 \
    /* Do nothing, just terminate */ \
  )
#define _MAP() MAP

#define STRINGIZE(x) #x
#define MAGIC_MACRO(...) EVAL(MAP(STRINGIZE, __VA_ARGS__))
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there's a more efficient way, but you can simply use Boost.PP:

```
#define MAGIC_MACRO_ELEM(r, data, i, elem) \
    BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(i) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem)

#define MAGIC_MACRO(...) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(MAGIC_MACRO_ELEM, ~, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ((__VA_ARGS__)))
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a3eea3038d7013d)

Comment: Thanks but I'm not planning to use boost

Comment: @oneiros: You can use [the preprocessor library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) without having to drag in the rest of Boost. ("The Boost Preprocessing library is a library of macros, with support for preprocessor metaprogramming. The library supports both C++ and C compilation. It does not depend on any other Boost libraries and therefore may be used as a standalone library.") So you can just download it and put it into your include directory. There is no binary file; the library consists only of macro definitions.

Comment: @Oneiros: Why not?

Comment: I was looking for a standard no-dependencies solution

Comment: @Oneiros: Your own code is precisely as much of a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is to have a separate macro for each different count. Using 2-level "stringify" macro pattern (read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989730/stringification-how-does-it-work)) you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#define XSTRINGIFY(s) #s

#define STRINGARRAY1(s0) { XSTRINGIFY(s0) }
#define STRINGARRAY2(s0, s1) { XSTRINGIFY(s0), XSTRINGIFY(s1) }
#define STRINGARRAY3(s0, s1, s2) { XSTRINGIFY(s0), XSTRINGIFY(s1), XSTRINGIFY(s2) }

using namespace std;

string dumpStrings(string *array, int count) {
    stringstream ss;
    if (count > 0) {
        ss << '"' << array[0] << '"';
        for(int i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
            ss << ", \"" << array[i]<< '"';
        }
    }
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    string strings1[1] = STRINGARRAY1(a);
    string strings2[2] = STRINGARRAY2(a, b);
    string strings3[3] = STRINGARRAY3(a, b, c);
    cout << "strings1: " << dumpStrings(strings1, sizeof(strings1) / sizeof(strings1[0])) << endl;
    cout << "strings2: " << dumpStrings(strings2, sizeof(strings2) / sizeof(strings2[0])) << endl;
    cout << "strings3: " << dumpStrings(strings3, sizeof(strings3) / sizeof(strings3[0])) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
strings1: "a"
strings2: "a", "b"
strings3: "a", "b", "c"
```

If you want just one macro which takes variable number of arguments, it gets a bit messy, as shown in the other answers.

Comment: Please don't put multiple statements on one line unless you have to. It severely impacts readability. As for a modernising suggestion: [`<array>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: Actually, if `dumpStrings` returned a string instead, it would become 1 statement on the line

Comment: Yeah. Edited a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this corresponds to what you're trying to achieve, but I generally use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907160/how-to-convert-enum-names-to-string-in-c) to generate strings (or other lists generated from the strings like enum elements).

E.g.,

```
#define FOREACH_APPLY(GENERATE) \
        GENERATE(a)   \
        GENERATE(b)  \
        GENERATE(c)

#define GENERATE_STRING(STRING) #STRING,

std::string myStrings[] = {
    FOREACH_APPLY(GENERATE_STRING)
};
```

Comment: This is what I am used to as well.  Is there a way to replace this with something like templates?