# Using an external version number in Haskell packages (Cabal)

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm working on a project that's chosen CMake as its build tool. The project is made up of several executables and since a few months back a few of them are written in Haskell. We strongly wish all executables to show the same version number when called as `foo --version`. Ideally that version should be recorded in one place, and ideally that place should be the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` (this is where the source for all the other executables get it, via the use of CMake's `configure_file` function).

Is there some nice way of achieving this?

Some extra information that might be useful:

- The source for each executable lives in its own dir, with its own *Cabal* file.
- We use `stack` to build, and there is a single `stack.yaml` file that points to all directories with Haskell code.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with CMake, but based on what the docs say about `configure_file`, it should work for Haskell as well, in much the same way you do it in C. You can have a field like `cpp-options: -DLIB_VERSION="${LIB_VERSION}"` (where `${LIB_VERSION}` is whichever variable identifies the version) in the prototype of your .cabal file, and then have `libVersion :: String; libVersion = LIB_VERSION` in some Haskell source file (in which `-XCPP` is enabled). You can do the same in the stack.yaml file with e.g. `ghc-options: "$everything": -D..`, which might be easier if you have many packages.

Comment: The issue with `configure_file`, as I see it, is that CMake likes to split building into a separate dir so the generated files end up out-of-source. This, unfortunately, isn't always so easy to deal with in Cabal+stack. Using CPP is something I didn't think of though, I'll look into passing the information via the build command instead of via a generated file.

Comment: "CMake likes to split building into a separate dir so the generated files end up out-of-source" - I'm not sure I understand  - can you not tell CMake to put a generated file in a particular place (the place being wherever stack/cabal expect their config files to be, i.e. at the root of the project source)? And yes, another option is to just pass `--cpp-options=-D..` on the command line to stack/cabal, which saves you from having to generate `stack.yaml` or `*.cabal` with configure_file - I guess depending on your particular setup, this could be easier or harder.

Comment: Yes, I can tell `configure_file` exactly where to put things, but I'd rather not go against the convention and put generated files in-source (it's already a point of contention that _stack_ leaves stuff in-source when building). Also, I kind of like that my Haskell bits are complete after check-out, i.e. I don't have to remember running CMake to generate missing bits before opening Haskell source in my editor (which integrates with intero/stack). I know, both reasons aren't very good but a solution that fulfils them both would be nice.

Comment: I think these are fine reasons (not wanting to interrupt your workflow, and not placing the undue burden of an additional dependency of your users for the purpose of a somewhat minor feature). Thanks for explaining! I suggest passing `-cpp-options=-D..` on the command line in the CMake build, and having `version :: Maybe String; #ifdef VERSION; version = Just VERSION; #else; version = Nothing` - this allows the package to be built without CMake (but then of course you have no knowledge of the version - but I think that's the best you can do).

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I just checked in :) I'll write a proper answer as soon as our CI is happy with the changes. There are a few details that might be worth documenting in a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd document the solution I've landed on.

#### the source changes

I added the *CPP* language extension and use a macro (`VERSION`) to chose between a version provided as a CPP macro and the version provided by Cabal:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
module Main where

import           Data.Version
import           Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
.... -- other imports

#ifdef VERSION
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
version = fst $ last $ readP_to_S parseVersion xstr(VERSION)
#else
import Paths_<Cabal project name> (version)
#endif
```

The need for the double-expansion (*xstr* and *str*) is explained in [the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989730/stringification-how-does-it-work#16990634).

#### building

The above code will unfortunately not build with a simple `stack build` command. This apparently has to do with the default CPP that *ghc* uses (`/usr/bin/gcc`) and the flags it passes to it (as I understand it the culprit is `-traditional`). The solution is to tell *ghc* to use GNU CPP:

```
stack build --ghc-options "-pgmP=/usr/bin/cpp -DVERSION=1.2.3"
```

or as I put it in my `CMakeLists.txt` (I use `ExternalProject` to integrate *stack* into our CMake-based build):

```
ExternalProject_Add(haskell-bits
...
BUILD_COMMAND cd <SOURCE_DIR>
  && ${HaskellStack_EXE} --local-bin-path <BINARY_DIR> --install-ghc
         install --ghc-options "-pgmP=/usr/bin/cpp -DVERSION=${<CMake proj name>_VERSION}"
...
)
```