# Read build arguments from NDK code

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an NDK file that inject my api key into my app, the code works correctly:

```
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_yt_javi_nftweets_ui_main_MainActivity_getTwitterKey(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

    return (*env)->  NewStringUTF(env, "my_twitter_key");
}
```

I would like to change *my_twitter_key* by an custom build argument

```
externalNativeBuild {
  ndkBuild {
    arguments "-DTWITTER_API_KEY=my_twitter_key"
  }
}
```

And read that argument inside the method *Java_yt_javi_nftweets_ui_main_MainActivity_getTwitterKey*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a define to your `cFlags` and [stringify it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989730/stringification-how-does-it-work) in your C code:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                cFlags "-DTWITTER_API_KEY=my_twitter_key"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s

...

return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, xstr(TWITTER_API_KEY));
```