# How do I differentiate flavors in an android NDK .c file

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I'm trying to solve a similar problem to [NDK support with different Product Flavour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350245/ndk-support-with-different-product-flavour) but in a .c file instead of a .cpp file.

Does anyone know how of if it's possible to get the current build flavor from the `JNIEnv` parameter in C like in the accepted C++ solution in the linked thread? And if not what is the most efficient way to have a function in C return a different string on each flavor.

My first instinct was to declare a different jni folder in each flavor in gradle by giving each an ExternalNativeBuild `NDKBuild` path, but it fails to build as gradle attempts to find a method `path()` in Android.mk opposed to setting the jni folder for the flavor.

Comment: Seems to me like [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47361259/1524450) to the question you linked to applies perfectly well in your case as well. Just use `cFlags` instead of `cppFlags`, and `const char*` instead of `std::string`. Or [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771588/read-build-arguments-from-ndk-code/46774983#46774983) should also work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have little to no experience with these C files, so I have a bit of a followup question. To use Alex's answer I add something like `#ifdef FLAVORONE
    const char* secret = "my_app_secret"
#endif` to the top of my keys.c file? Then how would I reference that defined variable to return it in my a function like `JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_mycompany_id_utilities_UtilFuncs_getSecret(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
    return (*env)->  NewStringUTF(env, secret); 
}`

Comment: Just like in the code you posted in your comment, i.e. pass the `const char*` to `NewStringUTF` and return the result.

Comment: I get "Can't resolve variable 'secret'" when I try to use the code in my post. Am I declaring it in the wrong place or not writing out the NewStringUTF call right?

Comment: Sounds like you either set the define incorrectly, or didn't declare a string for every possible define. But it's really impossible to say without having seen the code and build script.

Comment: I added a post with all my code in it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50240190/android-ndk-cflags-not-defined-for-product-flavors) I'd be very thankful if you could help me figure this out.