# android NDK cflags not defined for product flavors

Tags: android, android-ndk

In my gradle file I have

```
externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        flavorone{
            externalNativeBuild.cmake {
                cFlags '-DFLAVORONE'
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.flavoronerelease

        }         
        flavortwo{
            applicationId "com.mycompany.flavortwo"
            versionCode 2
            versionName "1.0.1"
            externalNativeBuild.cmake {
                cFlags '-DFLAVORTWO'
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.flavortworelease
        }
        flavorthree{
            applicationId "com.mycompany.flavorthree"
            versionCode 7
            versionName "1.0.6"
            externalNativeBuild.cmake {
                cFlags '-DFLAVORTHREE'
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.flavorthreerelease
        }
    }
```

To add defined variables to my c file so I can identify the flavor.
in my c file I have:

```
    const char* secret;
    #ifdef FLAVORONE
        const char* secret = "flavor_1_secret";
    #elif FLAVORTWO
        const char* secret = "flavor_2_secret";
    #elif FLAVORTHREE
        const char* secret = "flavor_3_secret";
    #else
        const char* secret = "flavor_1_secret";
    #endif

    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
    Java_com_mycompany_app_MainActivity_getSecret(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
        return (*env)->  NewStringUTF(env, secret);
}
```

The problem is when I compile and run my code in flavor 2 or 3 getSecret() returns "flavor_1_secret". I suspect I have done something wrong defining the variables with cflags, but am very new to working with the NDK and I am having trouble figuring out what I've done wrong. I also tried:

```
    const char* secret;
    #ifdef FLAVORTWO
        const char* secret = "flavor_2_secret";
    #else
        const char* secret = "flavor_1_secret";
    #endif

    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
    Java_com_mycompany_app_MainActivity_getSecret(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
        return (*env)->  NewStringUTF(env, secret);
}
```

and compiled it as flavor2. I still got the flavor 1 secret return. So it seems to always fall through the else and the flag variables are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to replace   `#elseif` by `#elif`, the preprocessor stops at `#ifdef` if it is **flavor 1** or jump to `#else` if other because `#elseif` is not defined

Comment: ah, what about the second scenario where I just used ifDef and else?

Comment: Thanks though, I fixed the elif problem and edited the original question.

Comment: BTW, what is the value of secret string in you method? It is always Null, did you forgot something ?

Comment: it is being declared above in the ifdef statement.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see the gradle script

Comment: Did you tried with separated if statments ?if->endif, if->endif...?

Comment: it just never gets defined because it sees all the flavor variables I defined in flags as undefined. Not sure what's wrong with my gradle script, but the problem seems to be there.

Answer (score 1):

You use ndkBuild (via Android.mk), not cmake. Hence, in flavored section, you need

```
externalNativeBuild.ndkBuild
```

Comment: I changed the code to: `productFlavors {
        flavorone{
            externalNativeBuild. ndkBuild {
                cFlags '-DFLAVORONE'
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.flavoronerelease

        }         
        flavortwo{
            applicationId "com.mycompany. ndkBuild"
            versionCode 2
            versionName "1.0.1"
            externalNativeBuild.cmake {
                cFlags '-DFLAVORTWO'
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.flavortworelease
        }` And the flag variables are still not defined.

Comment: I see that some `cmake` is still there. It's hard to understand in format of comments. Please try to use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43442227/192373) to see what flags are actually passed to **ndk-build**.

Comment: Oops, missed some cmakes in the genericized code, but it was correct in my actual code. Looking at that link now. Thanks.