# Unit test for ensuring conditionally compiled code in c++

Tags: c++, c, googletest

This is a standard C++ ASSERT macro defined in my code -

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#define ASSERT(n)
#else
#define ASSERT(n) \
if (!(n)){  \
    printf("%s - Failed ", #n); \
    printf("On %s ", __DATE__); \
    printf("At %s ", __TIME__); \
    printf("In File %s ", __FILE__); \
    printf("At Line %d\n", __LINE__); \
    exit(1);}
#endif
```

I want to ensure that my build always contains this code, by binding a unit test around it. The test should check that if #DEBUG preprocessor is not supplied (i.e. it is release mode), a conditional check applied in unit test should fail with ASSERT macro failing and containing the message given above.

Is there an established way to achieve this? I am using google test framework to achieve this, but unable to achieve the result. Test fails with standard assertion message, not the custom assertion I am trying it to fail with.
My code is as below -

```
TEST(VerifyNormalInitialization, VerifyAssert)
{
    static int index = 0;
    static int num = 4;
    ASSERT(index == num);
    EXPECT_FATAL_FAILURE(ASSERT(index == num),"Failed");
}
```

Comment: what are the "standard" and "custom" assertion messages? Please include output and expected output in the question

Comment: your own `ASSERT` calls `exit(1)`, thats going to be not easy to test for. Why reinvent the wheel in the first place? There is already `assert`

Comment: `EXPECT_FATAL_FAILURE` only detects GoogleTest assertion failures. `exit(1)` would be caught only in a [death test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.8.0/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#death-tests), using `EXPECT_EXIT` or `EXPECT_DEATH`.

Comment: @idclev463035818 : Point taken about 'exit(1)'. Sounds like I am trying to split the hair.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen : Thanks for pointing out death test, exploring it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the obvious the following raises only an error when DEBUG is defined.

```
ASSERT(index == num);
ASSERT(index != num);
```

For unit tests for both cases: production and development, you need to compile both ways.

You might effect that by your own `#define/#undef DEBUG`.

Good practice? I do not know; I was not aware that this was something worthwile testing. Maybe just a verification that ASSERTs are active during development. And that is something for an installation check.

Comment: Thanks Joop! Idea behind unit test was to ensure other devs become aware that they have omitted the #defined assert macro in a compilation unit that is taking a few minutes to compile and build, and when run they wont find the failure information pointing to file and line number. A failing unit test would quickly highlight this. However, reading comments above and your answer, I get a feeling I am approaching this in wrong way and need to explore other options.

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar I love this kind of safeguards for all eventualities, but there are some "efficiency" practices like skipping unit tests. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
EXPECT_FATAL_FAILURE(if (!(index == num)){ ... },"Failed");
```

Does that look like valid C++? It is not.

Consider writing a macro which passes along `#n`, `__FILE__` etc to a proper function. If you insist on using a macro alone, then it needs to be a single expression and not a statement, something along the lines of:

```
#define STR2(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR2(x)

#define ASSERT(n)                                          \
(                                                          \
  fprintf(stderr,                                          \
          #n " - Failed on " __DATE__ " at " __TIME__      \
          " in file " __FILE__ " at line " STR(__LINE__)   \
         ),                                                \
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE)                                       \
)
```

This is using compile-time string concatenation to prepare the whole string. Everything in this expression is string literals, and two string literals such as `"hello"` and `"world"` get concatenated by the pre-processor as `"helloworld"`.

The "stringification" macros are just there to convert the integer `__LINE__` into a string literal. [Stringification - how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989730/stringification-how-does-it-work)

Note that the `),` is the comma operator, which is used to allow two function calls in the same expression.