# Use macro with token-pasting operator

Tags: c, macros

I am facing a problem while making a code more general, I want to replace hardcoded values with macro but I am facing this issue :

Original code :

```
#define io_dir_in(port, pin) NRF_P##port->PIN_CNF[pin] = (GPIO_PIN_CNF_DIR_Input << GPIO_PIN_CNF_DIR_Pos) + (GPIO_PIN_CNF_INPUT_Connect << GPIO_PIN_CNF_INPUT_Pos)

io_dir_in(0, 0);
```

I added :

```
#define A_Port  0
#define A_Pin   0
```

And replaced :

```
io_dir_in(A_Port, A_Pin);
```

But I get the error `identifer "NRF_PA_Port" is undefined` because `NRF_P` and `A_Port` are getting concatenated.
 Anyway to make it work ?

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989730/stringification-how-does-it-work. # and ## work the same in terms of expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "concatenation of tokens" is done **before** an expansion of tokens. You need to add an extra step of expansion in between.

```
#define io_dir_in_impl(port, pin) NRF_P##port->PIN_CNF[pin] = (GPIO_PIN_CNF_DIR_Input << GPIO_PIN_CNF_DIR_Pos) + (GPIO_PIN_CNF_INPUT_Connect << GPIO_PIN_CNF_INPUT_Pos)
#define io_dir_in(port, pin) io_dir_in_impl(port, pin)
```

Now *before* `io_dir_in_impl()` is expanded all its arguments are expanded. Thus `A_Port` will be replaced with `0`.

With this tweak `io_dir_in(A_Port, A_Pin);` expands as:

```
NRF_P0->PIN_CNF[0] = (GPIO_PIN_CNF_DIR_Input << GPIO_PIN_CNF_DIR_Pos) + (GPIO_PIN_CNF_INPUT_Connect << GPIO_PIN_CNF_INPUT_Pos);
```