# Expand the concatenated text to be a macro and then expand the Macro again

Tags: c, macros

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define X 2
#define N_1_T 50
#define N_2_T 49
#define PRINT() printf("id: %d", N_ ## X ## _T)

int main(void)
{
    PRINT();
    return 0;
}
```

I want `N_ ## X ## _T` to be expanded to `N_2_T` when I have the Macro `#define X 2`. If I change the Macro definition of X to be `#define X 1`, `N_ ## X ## _T` should be expanded to `N_1_T`.

But I do not know how to do this. I have searched and read many pages, but I just do not get what I should do to achieve the desired result.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated language tags. Your program is written in either C, or in C++. Not both.

Comment: As for solving your problem with the macro, for only two alternatives a conditional expression (with some comments about it) should suffice. Otherwise for only a handful of alternatives, a function and `switch` is good (don't forget the `default` case!). But for more you should probably resort to arrays to translate one value to another (with some added bounds-checking).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right. But the macro should work in both C and C++, I think. I know there are other ways to finish this kind of job, but I am just curious to know whether macro could do the same thing. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve what you want, the `X` macro must be expanded to the pre-processor token `2` before concatenation, so the macro containing the `##` must get passed an expanded `2`. It is very similar to this: [Stringification - how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989730/stringification-how-does-it-work)

You can solve this with a number of helper macros that enforce rescanning of the pp tokens:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define X 2
#define N_1_T 50
#define N_2_T 49

#define CONCAT(n) N_ ## n ## _T
#define GET_ID(n) CONCAT(n)
#define PRINT() printf("id: %d", GET_ID(X))

int main(void)
{
    PRINT();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
id: 49
```