# How to port ShaderToy to standalone OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl

I've been looking at [Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/).

I have questions regarding Shader code listed in examples. Are those fragment shaders? The syntax seem unfamiliar to me. I am confused about how examples are being rendered without vertex shader or initialization code, such as setting up of textures etc.

Can examples on Shadertoy be ported to standalone OpenGL program and if so how would one go about attempting that?

Answer (score 5):

The basic Shadertoy shader is just a fragment shader applied on a fullscreen quad. It has more advanced features (such as audio generation, VR-support and multi-pass rendering) but that is the basic idea.

So to convert into OpenGL program you would start with rendering a fullscreen rectangle with simple vertex shader and then use the fragment shader from Shadertoy. You might have to change the syntax slightly so check if you get any syntax errors when the shader is compiled.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very basic example of converting a shadertoy shader to work in an OpenGL context by drawing the shader onto to a screen size quad.
A few shadertoy specific uniforms like `iResolution` and `iTime` are sent to the shader and the shader is slightly modified (eg. `void mainImage...` becomes `void main()` etc..)

Courtesy of [GLSL ray tracing test on Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3sc3z4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

const char *vertexShaderSource = 
R"(#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;            
layout (location = 1) in vec2 inTexCoord;

out vec2 texCoord;
void main(){
    texCoord = inTexCoord;
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
})";

const char *fragmentShaderSource = 
R"(#version 330 core
in vec2 texCoord;
uniform vec2 iMouse;
uniform vec2 iResolution;
uniform float iTime;
out vec4 fragColor;
vec2 fragCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy;
#define PI 3.14159265359
#define TWOPI 6.28318530718
//drag the window LR to control roughness

//--graphics setting (lower = better fps)---------------------------------------------------------------------
#define AVERAGECOUNT 16
#define MAX_BOUNCE 32

//--scene data---------------------------------------------------------------------
#define SPHERECOUNT 6
//xyz = pos, w = radius
const vec4 AllSpheres[SPHERECOUNT]=vec4[SPHERECOUNT](
    vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0),//sphere A
    vec4(0.0,0.0,-1.0,2.0),//sphere B
    vec4(0.0,-1002.0,0.0,1000.0),//ground
    vec4(0.0,0.0,+1002,1000.0),//back wall
    vec4(-1004.0,0.0,0.0,1000.0),//left wall    
    vec4(+1004.0,0.0,0.0,1000.0)//right wall
);
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
float raySphereIntersect(vec3 r0, vec3 rd, vec3 s0, float sr) {
    // - r0: ray origin
    // - rd: normalized ray direction
    // - s0: sphere center
    // - sr: sphere radius
    // - Returns distance from r0 to first intersecion with sphere,
    //   or -1.0 if no intersection.
    float a = dot(rd, rd);
    vec3 s0_r0 = r0 - s0;
    float b = 2.0 * dot(rd, s0_r0);
    float c = dot(s0_r0, s0_r0) - (sr * sr);
    if (b*b - 4.0*a*c < 0.0) {
        return -1.0;
    }
    return (-b - sqrt((b*b) - 4.0*a*c))/(2.0*a);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
struct HitData
{
    float rayLength;
    vec3 normal;
};
HitData AllObjectsRayTest(vec3 rayPos, vec3 rayDir)
{
    HitData hitData;
    hitData.rayLength = 9999.0; //default value if can't hit anything

    for(int i = 0; i < SPHERECOUNT; i++)
    {
        vec3 sphereCenter = AllSpheres[i].xyz;
        float sphereRadius = AllSpheres[i].w;
        //----hardcode sphere pos animations-------------------------------------
        if(i == 0)
        {
            float t = fract(iTime * 0.7);
            t = -4.0 * t * t + 4.0 * t;
            sphereCenter.y += t * 0.7;
            
            sphereCenter.x += sin(iTime) * 2.0;
            sphereCenter.z += cos(iTime) * 2.0;
        }
             
        if(i == 1)
        {
            float t = fract(iTime*0.47);
            t = -4.0 * t * t + 4.0 * t;
            sphereCenter.y += t * 1.7;
            
            sphereCenter.x += sin(iTime+3.14) * 2.0;
            sphereCenter.z += cos(iTime+3.14) * 2.0;
        }             
        //---------------------------------------
                
        float resultRayLength = raySphereIntersect(rayPos,rayDir,sphereCenter,sphereRadius);
        if(resultRayLength < hitData.rayLength && resultRayLength > 0.001)
        {
            //if a shorter(better) hit ray found, update
            hitData.rayLength = resultRayLength;
            vec3 hitPos = rayPos + rayDir * resultRayLength;
        hitData.normal = normalize(hitPos - sphereCenter);
        }
    }
    
    //all test finished, return shortest(best) hit data
    return hitData;
}
//--random functions-------------------------------------------------------------------
float rand01(float seed) { return fract(sin(seed)*43758.5453123); }
vec3 randomInsideUnitSphere(vec3 rayDir,vec3 rayPos, float extraSeed)
{
    return vec3(rand01(iTime * (rayDir.x + rayPos.x + 0.357) * extraSeed),
                rand01(iTime * (rayDir.y + rayPos.y + 16.35647) *extraSeed),
                rand01(iTime * (rayDir.z + rayPos.z + 425.357) * extraSeed));
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
vec4 calculateFinalColor(vec3 cameraPos, vec3 cameraRayDir, float AAIndex)
{
    //init
    vec3 finalColor = vec3(0.0);
    float absorbMul = 1.0;
    vec3 rayStartPos = cameraPos;
    vec3 rayDir = cameraRayDir;
    
    //only for CineShader, to show depth
    float firstHitRayLength = -1.0;
    
    //can't write recursive function in GLSL, so write it in a for loop
    //will loop until hitting any light source / bounces too many times
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_BOUNCE; i++)
    {
        HitData h = AllObjectsRayTest(rayStartPos + rayDir * 0.0001,rayDir);//+0.0001 to prevent ray already hit at start pos
        
        //only for CineShader, to show depth
        firstHitRayLength = firstHitRayLength < 0.0 ? h.rayLength : firstHitRayLength;
               
        //if ray can't hit anything, rayLength will remain default value 9999.0
        //which enters this if()
        //** 99999 is too large for mobile, use 9900 as threshold now **
        if(h.rayLength >= 9900.0)
        {
            vec3 skyColor = vec3(0.7,0.85,1.0);//hit nothing = hit sky color
            finalColor = skyColor * absorbMul;
            break;
        }   
               
    absorbMul *= 0.8; //every bounce absorb some light(more bounces = darker)
        
        //update rayStartPos for next bounce
    rayStartPos = rayStartPos + rayDir * h.rayLength; 
        //update rayDir for next bounce
        float rougness = 0.05 + iMouse.x / iResolution.x; //hardcode "drag the window LR to control roughness"
    rayDir = normalize(reflect(rayDir,h.normal) + randomInsideUnitSphere(rayDir,rayStartPos,AAIndex) * rougness);       
    }
    
    return vec4(finalColor,firstHitRayLength);//alpha nly for CineShader, to show depth
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
void main() {
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;
    
  uv = uv * 2.0 - 1.0;//transform from [0,1] to [-1,1]
    uv.x *= iResolution.x / iResolution.y; //aspect fix

    vec3 cameraPos = vec3(sin(iTime * 0.47) * 4.0,sin(iTime * 0.7)*8.0+6.0,-25.0);//camera pos animation
    vec3 cameraFocusPoint = vec3(0,0.0 + sin(iTime),0);//camera look target point animation
    vec3 cameraDir = normalize(cameraFocusPoint - cameraPos);
    
    //TEMPCODE: fov & all ray init dir, it is wrong!!!!
    //----------------------------------------------------
    float fovTempMul = 0.2 + sin(iTime * 0.4) * 0.05;//fov animation
    vec3 rayDir = normalize(cameraDir + vec3(uv,0) * fovTempMul);
    //----------------------------------------------------

    vec4 finalColor = vec4(0);
    for(int i = 1; i <= AVERAGECOUNT; i++)
    {
        finalColor+= calculateFinalColor(cameraPos,rayDir, float(i));
    }
    finalColor = finalColor/float(AVERAGECOUNT);//brute force AA & denoise
    finalColor.rgb = pow(finalColor.rgb,vec3(1.0/2.2));//gamma correction
    
    //only for CineShader, to show depth
    float z = finalColor.w; //z is linear world space distance from camera to surface
    float cineShaderZ; //expect 0~1
    cineShaderZ = pow(clamp(1.0 - max(0.0,z-21.0) * (1.0/6.0),0.0,1.0),2.0);
    
    //result
    fragColor = vec4(finalColor.rgb,cineShaderZ);
})";

int main()
{
    int width = 800;
    int height = 600;

    glm::vec2 screen(width, height);

    float deltaTime = 0.0f; 
    float lastFrame = 0.0f; 

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "OpenglContext", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!window)
    {
        std::cerr << "failed to create window" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cerr << "failed to initialize glad with processes " << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    int samples = 4;
    float quadVerts[] = {
        -1.0, -1.0,     0.0, 0.0,
        -1.0, 1.0,      0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0,      1.0, 0.0,

        1.0, -1.0,      1.0, 0.0,
        -1.0, 1.0,      0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,       1.0, 1.0
    };

    GLuint VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quadVerts), quadVerts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), reinterpret_cast<void*>(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), reinterpret_cast<void*>(2 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindVertexArray(0);


    GLuint framebuffer;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer); 

    GLuint texColor;
    glGenTextures(1, &texColor);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texColor);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texColor, 0);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);


    //vertex shader
    unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // fragment shader
    unsigned int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // check for shader compile errors

    // link shaders
    unsigned int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    // check for linking errors

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "iResolution"), 1, &screen[0]);


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame; 

        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
        }

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);


        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "iTime"), (int)currentFrame % 60); 
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }
    glfwTerminate();
    // cleanup
}
```

[image: shadertoy running in opengl context]

Could do other things to make it better including:

- adding texture samplers (`iChannel0`, `iChannel1`, etc...)
- multiple files
- loading shader from external file instead of hard coding

Comment: [Use C++11 raw string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13872584/44729) to save a bunch of `"` and `\n` characters :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to join this project.

It implement most of the function. just need to extend some class for cubemap, audio texture etc.

https://github.com/MacgyverLin/GLSLRayMarching.git

Comment: you need to update submodule for a rapidjason