# GCC: how to fix or suppress the warning: unknown escape sequence: '\#'

Tags: c, gcc, opengl-es

The OpenGL ES shader code is defined as a C string. To make writing the shader code more intuitively, I define a macro named `SHADER_STRING(code)` like below. But I encounter a GCC warning `unknown escape sequence: '\#'` and don't know how to suppress it or fix it.

A example code is below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
#define _SHADER_STRING(code) #code
#define SHADER_STRING(code) _SHADER_STRING(code)
    // OpenGL ES Shader codes
    char vShaderStr[] = SHADER_STRING(
        \#version 300 es \n

        void main()
        {
            // ... some OpenGL ES codes.
        });
    printf("%s\n", vShaderStr);
    return 0;
}
```

Because the `#version` is a preprocessor supported by OpenGL ES 3.0, then it's invalid to replace the `\#` with `\\#`, otherwise the codes will become

```
\#version 300 es
void main() { }
```

The OpenGL shader compiler will complained knowing nothing about the `\#version` .

Comment: What about simply `#version …`?

Comment: Your [mcve] doesn't compile and your question is not clear.

Comment: What is `TS_SHADER_STRING`? Only `SHADER_STRING` is defined in the code fragment. `\#` simply becomes `#` with the mentioned warning. Why the escape at all? I've got a hunch that you copy-pasted this code from somewhere else and took it out of it's parsing context while doing so.

Comment: Why on earth do you want the text pretending to be `void main() …` as part of the version string?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This's a OpenGL ES shader code which must have a main function.

Comment: @dhke I've fixed the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13874526), the following code should work:

```
#define GLSL(version, shader)  "#version " #version "\n" #shader

const GLchar* vShaderStr_30 = GLSL(300,
    void main() {
        …
    }
);
```

Comment: The string is a OpenGL ES shader code. `#version` is a macro supported by OpenGL ES 3.0 but not by 2.0. So if using your implementation, I must define two versions of `SHADER_STRING`.

Comment: It seems there is only one resolution that is defining two versions of `SHADER_STRING`, i.e., `SHADER_STRING2` and `SHADER_STRING3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define _SHADER_STRING(str) #str
#define SHADER_STRING(str) _SHADER_STRING(str)
// OpenGL ES Shader codes
char vShaderStr_30[] = SHADER_STRING(#version 300 es \n

    void main()
    {
         // ...
    });
```

But without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to have a better answer.