# VS: Include ressource files in build/exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, include, shader

I am wirting an OpengGL-program and I have a lot of shader files (basically text-files), that are loaded into my OpenGL software. Inside Visual Studio everything works fine, but if I doubleclick the compiled exe-file outside of VS, these files are missing. Is there a way to include these files into the build/exe at compile-time, without manually copy all those files into the builddriectory? Inside VS the files are stored as "ressource files".

Comment: [Raw string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13872584/44729) work pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is probably just to set up a post build event that copies the files into the exe directory for you.

Here's a link to some documentation on it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/specifying-build-events?view=vs-2017

Effectively how build events work is that you can specify pre-build and post-build events. For both you can just enter command line commands to run. So in the post-build steps you can use a command line copy command (xcopy, robocopy, etc) to copy the resource files into the exe folder.