# Can you write OpenGL shader in different file and later link it to the program?

Tags: c++

Can you write OpenGL shader in a different file and later link it to the program? and if it's possible how? writing OpenGL shader in `string` makes my code messy.

Here is example code for shaders:

```cpp
const char* vertexShaderSource =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;\n"
    "\n"
    "out vec3 ourColor;\n"
    "uniform vec2 angleValues;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x * angleValues.x - aPos.y * angleValues.y, aPos.y * angleValues.x + aPos.x * angleValues.y , aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
    "ourColor = aColor;\n"
    "}\n";

const char* fragmentShaderSource =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "in vec3 ourColor;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "FragColor = vec4(ourColor, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";
```

Comment: "writing OpenGL shader in string makes my code messy."  [C++11 raw string literals make it much cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13872584/44729), no need for all the `\n`'s.

Comment: yes, you can; it's very easy to read a file into a `const char*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have files like `my_shader.vs` or `my_fragment.fs` and link them like in this [Shader class](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=includes/learnopengl/shader_s.h)

Just initialize it like this:

```cpp
shader = Shader("./shaders/my_shader.vs", "./shaders/my_fragment.fs");
```

Comment: Thanks, btw, can u tell me how to link those files into shader class?

Comment: Just use the example initialization I've given. Make sure the files are there and the path is proper, use absolute path if needed. If you need more documentation look at this example: https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/3.3.shaders_class/shaders_class.cpp

Comment: @NikoMolecule If these helped can you please accept my answer?

Comment: This isn't linked - you made the program load the shader at run-time.

Comment: @Turgut yes it helped, i forgot to accept it

Comment: also, pointing to an external tutorial isn't really accepted in SO answers